# call by value: what is a value?

Tags: lambda-calculus, functional-programming, term-rewriting, types-and-programming-languages

In the 'call by value' evaluation of lambda-calculus, I am bit confused with  'value'.

On page 57 of the book [Types and Programming languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/), it is said:

> The definition of call by value, in which only outermost redexes are reduced and where a redex is reduced only when its right-hand side has already been reduced to a value - a term that is finished computing and cannot be reduced any further.

So by that definition, a term `λx.x` is a value, but a term `λx.((λy.y)x)` is not a value since it can be reduced further.

But in an example of 'call by value' on the same page, reduction as the following. (`id` is the identity function `λx.x`)

```
id (id (λz.id z))
   -------------- 
id (λz.id z)
------------
λz.id z
```

But in this example neither

```
  (id (λz.id z))
```

is a value, nor

```
  (λz.id z)
```

a value.

Isn't contradictions here? or I am misunderstanding something?

Can anyone clarify these to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The set of values is defined for a particular reduction relation. Each reduction relation defines its own set of values.

Reduction for the lambda calculus isn't just beta reduction, there are also **context rules**. There are several common notions of reduction for the lambda calculus, with different sets of context rules.

In the full lambda calculus, any lambda term with a hole is a context: the context rules are
$$
\frac{M \to M'}{M\,N \to M'\,N} \qquad
\frac{N \to N'}{M\,N \to M\,N'} \qquad
\frac{M \to M'}{\lambda x.M \to \lambda x.M'}
$$
This doesn't mimic what most programming languages do. Most programming languages don't start evaluating a function's body before the function receives its arguments (this becomes especially important when evaluating the function body causes side effects). This translates into omitting the third rule above altogether: there is no reduction under a lambda. The reduction relation without that context rule is known as *weak head reduction*. For weak head reduction, $\lambda x. M$ is a value for any term $M$: even if $M$ could be reduced, $\lambda x. M$ can't.

Call-by-value and call-by-name are refinements of weak head reduction which also restrict the form of terms that rules can be applied to: the first two rules above, and the beta rule, have constraints on the form of $M$ or $N$.

As far as I recall, TAPL focuses on applications of the lambda calculus to programming and so focuses on weak head reduction. `(λz.id z)` is a value. `(id (λz.id z))` isn't a value, which is why the first step reduces it (the first step is `id M → id M'` where `M → M'`: it's the `id` in the argument that reduces, not the outer `id`).

Comment: "this becomes especially important when evaluating the function body causes side effects" Indeed! And fixed point combinators could also diverge, in practice, if we insist on reducing under lambdas.

Comment: I think now I understood the value and call by value stuff. I read all these things before, but haven't read their connections as you explained. Thanks!